# Angular 2 Image Binding from the local hard disk

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I am having an issue while binding the Image path to img src in angular 2.
I am saving the image in localdisk and saving the path in the database and retrieving the image path and binding to the img source tag but it is not binding. I tried to bind the local disk url directly to the image tag then i am getting error "**Not Allowed to load local resources.**", If i bind the local path value to  **SafeUrl variable** then the error is **unsafe:E:\Main Projects\img\20182201521541566536.jpg:1**

can any one please give me some solution.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read files from your harddrive as image source. You need to provide the images in your project, so they are available on localhost.

Comment: I have scenario where the user will upload the images. i am saving those images in the project folder itself but after building the angular 2 only the images are displaying in the gallery other wise it is showing the error "file not found"

Answer (score 0):

I have one more solution for it and its working for me. We can host our images on IIS and then we can provide the http path to SRC of IMG tag.
When you deploy your code to any live server then you have to pass the http path of images as per the live server settings.
Browsers consider those URLs as unsafe which dont have http attached to them.

If anyone still finding any issue then please let me know, I'll share my code here.

Answer (score -1):

Below works for me

Step 1 ) import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

Step 2 )Then in constructor add the dependency
public _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer

Step 3 )Now bind property as

this.ImagePath = this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.FilePath);